# How to print a value of a dictionairy, based on the previous key value? (where the key is a date)

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary, data-science

I have a large amount of sport data that I am analyzing. I am trying to find the last location of the team (the time zone).

I have decided that creating a dictionary is a viable option.

This is what I have got so far which outputs the game data and timezone.

```
                schedule_ANA=dict()
                #ANA is the team I'm interested in
                if str(hometeam) == "ANA" or str(awayteam) == "ANA":
                    schedule_ANA[date]=str(timezone)
                    # This finds the time zone of the game on that date
                    print (schedule_ANA)
```

This is the output

```
 {'2018/09/08': 'GMT-5'}
 {'2018/09/09': 'GMT-5'}
 {'2018/08/03': 'GMT-4'}
 {'2018/08/04': 'GMT-4'}
 {'2018/08/05': 'GMT-4'}
 {'2018/05/08': 'GMT-6'}
 {'2018/05/09': 'GMT-6'}
 {'2018/05/28': 'GMT-4'}
 {'2018/05/29': 'GMT-4'}
 {'2018/05/30': 'GMT-4'}
 {'2018/05/31': 'GMT-4'}
 {'2018/04/23': 'GMT-5'}
 {'2018/04/24': 'GMT-5'}
 {'2018/08/28': 'GMT-7'}
 {'2018/04/25': 'GMT-5'}
 {'2018/09/01': 'GMT-5'}
```

Now I need to consider the PREVIOUS time zone from that date.

I want to find the time zone of the last game. I want to go back 1 day at a time until the next game date/time zone occurs.

For example, if a game is on 28 August 2018 at GMT-7,  no game on 29,30 or 31 August, then another game at 1 September 2018 at GMT -5, I want a function to
return GMT -7 when 1 September 2018 is the input.

I want to use an if statement to say

```
  if date == 2018/09/01
  previous_date=date-1
  previous_timezone= schedule_ANA[previous_date]
```

I am unsure of the following things
1. if this is the correct syntax for a dictionary
2. How to convert the date to a format so this will work (go back 1 day to the previous month)

Thanks in advance!

-

### -

***EDIT***
Thank you to everyone who has commented. I am trying to implement some of the solutions in the answers. This is my updated code but I am still getting an error

```
                schedule_ANA=dict()
                #ANA is the team I'm interested in
                if str(hometeam) == "ANA" or str(awayteam) == "ANA":
                    schedule_ANA[date]=str(timezone)
                    # This finds the time zone of the game on that date
                    print (schedule_ANA)

                    from datetime import datetime
                    from ast import literal_eval
                    schedule_ANA = [literal_eval(i) for i in schedule_ANA]
                    sorted_dates = sorted([(k,v)for i in schedule_ANA for k,v in i.items()], key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0], "%Y/%m/%d"))
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/2019sem2/egh400/Code/rev40.py", line 147, in <module>
    schedule_ANA = [literal_eval(i) for i in schedule_ANA]
  File "H:/2019sem2/egh400/Code/rev40.py", line 147, in <listcomp>
    schedule_ANA = [literal_eval(i) for i in schedule_ANA]
  File "C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS 25\Python3\lib\ast.py", line 46, in     literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS 25\Python3\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    2018/04/03
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Comment: Convert your output to a `list of dicts` and take the previous date by using index value.

Comment: @shaikmoeed Thanks for your comment, the issue is, the dictionary is not currently ordered by date.

Answer (score 0):

As @shaik moeed pointed out. use a list.

```
def get_last_date(date_str):
    return [x for x in schedule_ANA.keys()].index(date_str) - 1
```

Above code will give Value error if date_str is not in the schedule_ANA dict.

```
def get_last_date(date_str):
    return next((x for x in schedule_ANA.keys()), [-1]) - 1
```

Above code has a default value of -1 if the date_str is not in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

I have converted your dictionary to list of tuples and sorted by dates.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> dates_list
[{'2018/09/08': 'GMT-5'}, {'2018/09/09': 'GMT-5'}, {'2018/08/03': 'GMT-4'}, {'2018/08/04': 'GMT-4'}, {'2018/08/05': 'GMT-4'}, {'2018/05/08': 'GMT-6'}, {'2018/05/09': 'GMT-6'}, {'2018/05/28': 'GMT-4'}, {'2018/05/29': 'GMT-4'}, {'2018/05/30': 'GMT-4'}, {'2018/05/31': 'GMT-4'}, {'2018/04/23': 'GMT-5'}, {'2018/04/24': 'GMT-5'}, {'2018/08/28': 'GMT-7'}, {'2018/04/25': 'GMT-5'}, {'2018/09/01': 'GMT-5'}]

# if elements are in string, to convert them to actual data type, here dictionary,
# follow below steps
# >>> from ast import literal_eval
# >>> dates_list = [literal_eval(i) for i in dates_list]

>>> sorted_dates = sorted([(k,v)for i in dates_list for k,v in i.items()], key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0], "%Y/%m/%d"))
[('2018/04/23', 'GMT-5'), ('2018/04/24', 'GMT-5'), ('2018/04/25', 'GMT-5'), ('2018/05/08', 'GMT-6'), ('2018/05/09', 'GMT-6'), ('2018/05/28', 'GMT-4'), ('2018/05/29', 'GMT-4'), ('2018/05/30', 'GMT-4'), ('2018/05/31', 'GMT-4'), ('2018/08/03', 'GMT-4'), ('2018/08/04', 'GMT-4'), ('2018/08/05', 'GMT-4'), ('2018/08/28', 'GMT-7'), ('2018/09/01', 'GMT-5'), ('2018/09/08', 'GMT-5'), ('2018/09/09', 'GMT-5')]
```

Now you can check the previous dates by using index values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @shaikmoeed. I am new to python and struggling with the implementation. The actual output from the dictionary is a lot longer. I added in the line 


I added the line   "sorted_dates = sorted([(k,v)for i in schedule_ANA for k,v in i.items()], key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0], "%Y/%m/%d"))"  after print(schedule_ANA) at the same indentation level as the lineschedule_ANA=dict()

Is that on the right track? I got an error when I tried to run it

Comment: @Lauren No, you need to keep after `if-block` or below your output where your printing the output provided in question i,e., `print (schedule_ANA)`

Comment: thank you again for the reply. I have moved it to the end of the if-statement inline with the indentation of "print (schedule_ANA)". Now it is producing this error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'"

Comment: @Lauren check the updated answer. Your dictionary is in string format. Use `literal_eval` to read them `dict`

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to implement that but am still getting errors. I think it may have to do with the format of the date. I've made an edit to the original post which shows the error